# How to use two providers with same username in a realm/client in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I have keycloak instance (version 16) with one realm and two different clients.

The first client works with Open ID Connect Identity provider. It also works with `public` Access Type and with SSO and 2FA.
The second client works with a Custom module added from `User Federation` where 2FA is not possible to be used because the calls for authentication are mainly programmatically. Also, this client works with `confidential` Access Type.

The problem is that each client has a different external database with users, but the usernames in these databases are not unique.

And if I try to log in with the second client it works but after that, if I try to log in with the first client I can't, and vice versa. (in both clients username "notUniqueUser@email.com" is used)

The error message in this case is:

```
User with username notUniqueUser@email.com already exists. How do you want to continue?
    “Review profile”
    “Add to existing account”
```

Is it possible for these two clients to work both properly at the same time, when I do not have unique usernames and how should I configure it? (I find that is possible to have same email addresses but I can't find anything for usernames)
Maybe some kind of force authentication will be OK, and when the user "notUniqueUser@email.com" is already logged with the first client and I try to log in with the second, the session from the first one to be deleted and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how your IDPs are configured you can try the following:

- go to your realm
- then to the IDP configuration in question
- switch to Mappers
- Click on `Create`
- As a mapper type select `Username teamplate Importer`
- in the template field and something that will make the username unique for example ${CLAIM.preferred_username}_`<The Name of the IDP>`

For example, if a username named 'user' logins from both 'IDP1' and 'IDP2' it will be imported into the Keycloak DB as 'user_IDP1' and 'user_IDP2', respectively.